# Stalks of invertible sheaves on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have just found out that I have maybe not understood very well what an invertible sheaf looks like.

Let $X$ be a (regular, integral, separated, whatever you want) curve and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on it. Suppose moreover that $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(D)$ where $D=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i p_i$ is an effective divisor on $X$, i.e. $a_i>0$ for every $i$. I can interpret global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ as regular functions on $X$ with at most poles of order $a_i$ in the point $p_i$. (Here I define the order of a pole of a rational function using the valuation map on each local ring). I am implicitly thinking at $\mathcal{L}$ as a subsheaf of the rational functions sheaf $\mathcal{K}_X$ as explained in Hartshorne, page 144.

I want to understand what is the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at each point, i.e. $\mathcal{L}_p=\,$? for $p\in X$.

I have thought that since the question is local, I can restrict to an open affine neighbourhood of $p$ where $\mathcal{L}$ looks like the structure sheaf. This leaded me to state that if $p\notin \rm{Supp}\,D$, then $\mathcal{L}_p=\mathcal{O}_p$. But apparently the same argument applies even if $p\in\rm{Supp}\,D$, which is absurd.

Hence I have two questions:

1) Where does my argument fail?

2) What is $\mathcal{L}_p$ if $p\in\rm{Supp}\,D$?

Any hint or comment will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For any line bundle $L$ and any point $p$, $L_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_p$. In fact, you can take this as an alternate definition of a line bundle, for coherent sheaves.

Comment: The question may be whether $\mathcal O_p$ and $\mathcal L_p$ are the same subring of the function field.

Comment: @Mohan, I am a bit confused. If I know that $\mathcal{L}_p\cong\mathcal{O}_p$, doesn't it imply that $\mathcal{L}\cong\mathcal{O}$, i.e. do stalks uniquely (up to iso) determine the sheaf?

Comment: Mohan, @Hoot, how can we then think at $\mathcal{L}_p$ when $p$ is in the support of $D$?

Comment: @user273503, No, stalks do not determine a sheaf in the abstract. If you think of $L$ as a subsheaf of the constant sheaf $K$ of rational functions, then for any open  set $U$, you can think of $L(U)$ as the set of  all rational functions with poles of order at most $a_i$ for all $p_i\in U$.

Comment: @Mohan, so this means that $\mathcal{L}_p$ is the same (up to iso) for every invertible sheaf!? I still cannot realise it: this would mean that if I consider $X=\mathbb{A^1}$, then $\mathcal{L}_p=\mathbb{C}[x]_{(p)}$: how can I see if a function has a pole in $p$ from this?

Comment: Do not use equality, they are isomorphisms. You can see nothing locally, if you do what you do. For affine line, these are even global isomorphisms. For ANY divisor $D$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$, $L(D)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$.

Comment: @Mohan, ok I see, but then what is the advantage in defining properties locally at stalk-level if (up to iso) they are all the same? I mean, e.g. in my question, if $s\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$ has a pole in $p$, then the image $(s)_p$ of $s$ in the stalk $\mathcal{L}_p$ "forgets" the pole?

Comment: I think you are confusing `global' with `local'. To say $s$ has a pole at $p$ makes no sense unless you have a line bundle. For example $L\subset M$, then if $s$ is a global section of $L$, then it is also a global section of $M$. But, it can have a pole at a point for one and not the other.

Comment: @Mohan, I've got my problem: a pole is a zero in another chart and so locally there is no problem. Sorry for being so dumb and thank you.